# MySQL Server command mysqld is not working

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, server

(Windows 7) I just installed MySQL Server 5.7 using the **MSI installer**, therefore as I understand, it is installed as **Windows Service**.

I am having trouble launching the server using the command:

```
C:\>mysqld
```

After issuing this command in command line, nothing happens. The cursor just keeps blinking and I get stuck.

If I try to launch the server using Windows Services I get the following message:

*"The MySQL104 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."*

*(MySQL104 is the server name that I specified during the installation)

Also if I try to run this service via command line as service using command:

```
C:\>net start MySQL104
```

I get the answer:

```
C:\>net start MySQL104
The MySQL104 service is starting.
The MySQL104 service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.


C:\>net helpmsg 3534

The service did not report an error.
```

Right now the only way for me to reboot the server is to reboot my whole system, for it starts automatically at system startup.

I am running the command line as administrator. I am out of ideas.

Comment: You need to read the MySQL Server error log file. When a service crashes Windows knows nothing about the details.

Answer (score 0):

The service is actually started, with no logs. You can run queries. (the .err log file in `data` folder also says this).

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the my.ini configure file
2. Check the my.err(the file name is depend on your configure) for any error information
3. Fix all the errors

Comment: That's not helpful

Comment: Could you provide more information about this?, maybe a reference to the "docs".